# Ember model's 'hasMany' relation not loaded

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around ember.js.

I have two models, Recording and Comment (imagine a classical Post and Comment example).

What I'm doing is displaying all the recordings on one page, along with all the comments for each recording.  Next to each recording is a input box to create a new comment for that recording.

Now, everything seems to work OK.  I can add a comment and it's dynamically added to the list of comments for that recording.  But when I refresh the page, comments are not displayed, only the Recording.

I'm displaying the comments using a nested {{#each}} loop, but since it's working fine when I dynamically add a comment, I'm not sure if that's the problem.

There is a (updated) JSBin here:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/worulexe/12/edit

***UPDATE***

So, I've figured out that the Record model's relationships (to comments) aren't populated on load.  Why is that?

```
// The models are loaded like this in the IndexRoute
   this.store.find('recording'); // <- this loads all the record models, but doesn't set the "comments" relations.
```

Server returns

```
{
"comments": [{"id":1,"text":"Invisible when page loaded","recording_id":1}],
"recordings":[
{"id":1,"filename":"rec-01.mp3","comment_ids":[1]},
{"id":2,"filename":"rec-02.mp3","comment_ids":[]}
]
}
```

The first record should have one comment, but it isn't loaded?

Comment: I have a similar problem, on my side. It's working 4 out of 5 . Some racing condition :O ? But try debugging your route ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the ruddy problem.  Hope this saves someone else hours and hours of frustration and strong negative emotions towards Ember's documentation.

Turns out that if you use the "active_model_serializers" Gem for Rails (ActiveModel::Serializers) you need to use Ember's 
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend() and 
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend()

Ember is a wonderful project, but it's documentation makes me go completely nuts.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code in your JSBin.

```
// Default index route
App.Route = Ember.Route.extend({
    ...
});
```

That does not declare a route for the `index` route, that declares a route that *all* generated routes inherit from. And since you didn't declare any routes, *all* of your routes will inherit from it, and *all* of your routes will have the same model. Use `App.IndexRoute` instead.

And that brings me to point two. Your `ApplicationController` extends from `ArrayController`, so the model it expects is some type of array. But because of the above, your model is actually an object, which is why your `each` loop is not executing.

If you fix those issues and update your JSBin, we can probably help you with your root problem with the nested `each` loop (if it's still a problem).

Comment: Thanks for the routes hint, it solved the problem I had with JSBin.  The main problem turned out to be with the JSON format (see answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22882752/3484659).  I thought I was following Ember's documentation, but the doc might have been a week old.